# How to change the default button on gVim's W11 ("File has changed") warning popup?

Tags: vim, gvim

When working with a file that is regularly changing externally, a popup warning dialog is opened, asking whether to keep buffer contents (the default) or load the updated file into the buffer:

[image]

Is it possible to change the default button to `Load File` instead of `OK`, so a single press on <kbd>Enter</kbd> reloads the file?

I am aware of the `autoread` option, but I still want to be able to control the update.

Comment: Many will argue that the default is so for a reason, namely to avoid accidentally overriding the edited contents with an inadvertent press of Enter.

Comment: @IngoKarkat - Obviously, but I want to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you'd have to **modify Vim's source code** and compile your own version.

Alternatively, you can hook into the `FileChangedShell` event and implement your own emulation of the original dialog (with `confirm()`); `:help FileChangedShell` has all the details on that.

Comment: Thanks. Vim is just amazing. Every time a semi-advanced question is answered, it opens a Pandora's box... Looking at the suggested help page, there seems to be a whole new world of those events...

Comment: So I wanted to test this thing. Defiend a new group `:aug my_test_group`. Then, defined an autocmd: `au my_test_group FileChangedShell * confirm("TEST","&Y\n&N",2,"W")`. Changed the buffered file externally. When returned focus to gVim, I get an error: `E492: Not an editor command: confirm(...`. I cannot run the `confirm()` command from the `:` command prompt either.

Comment: OK, got it. I can do `let a=confirm(...`

Comment: Please see my follow up question here: http://superuser.com/q/731979/45564 . Thanks.