# How to determine what buffer was changed externally with gVim?

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc, gvimrc

I am using the following Vim autocommand in my `.gvimrc` file:

```
augroup MyAuGroup
  autocmd MyAuGroup FileChangedShell * call FileChanedEvent_BuffUpdate()
augroup END

function FileChanedEvent_BuffUpdate()
  let MyBn  = bufname("%")
  let MyStr = "Warning: File \"".MyBn."\" has changed since editing started\nSee \":help W11\" for more info."
  let MyTest = confirm(MyStr, "&OK\n&Load File", 2, "W")
  if MyTest == 2
    edit
  else
  endif
endfunction
```

with the intention to replace the default gVim behaviour when a file is changed externally (see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/731882/45564)). However, if multiple windows are opened, showing multiple buffers, the `edit` command works on the last active window, and not on the window containing the buffer that was changed.

How can I determine which buffer caused the `FileChangedShell` event, and apply the `edit` commant to that buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @IngoKarkat's answer. I found an alternative solution. Replace the `if` block in the function with:

```
  if MyTest == 2
    let v:fcs_choice = "reload"
  else
    let v:fcs_choice = ""
  endif
```

This seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

From `:help FileChangedShell`:

> ```
> NOTE: When this autocommand is executed, the
> current buffer "%" may be different from the
> buffer that was changed "<afile>".
> ```

You need to locate the window where the corresponding file is being edited. For that, the buffer number (in `<abuf>`) is even easier:

```
let winNr = bufwinnr(0 + expand('<abuf>'))
execute winNr . 'wincmd w'
edit
```

The same applies to the buffer name; replace

```
let MyBn  = bufname("%")
```

with

```
let MyBn  = expand('<afile>')
```

Comment: I used `edit MyBn` instead of the `edit` command. But, when selecting the `load File` button, I get error `E811` and the buffer won't update. I think my alternative answer is more direct.

Comment: I wonder why there is a difference between the two `edit` forms. The `edit` (no args) version works when the last active buffer was the one with the changed file.

Comment: tried also `edit <afile>` but got the same response

Comment: You would need `execute 'edit' fnameescape(MyBn)`, but I see you've found a more straightforward alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately, this variation fails either.